# Cannot use pip3.5 when in the root mode

Tags: linux, bash, fedora

I have installed Python3.5 from source for `fedora`. Now I can use `python3.5` by just type `python3.5` or `python3` in the cmd line when I am not in the root mode. It also works when I use `pip3.5`. However, when I log in as `root`, it links `python3` to the old 3.4 version and the cmd line does not recognize `pip3.5`. The bash line is like this:[seke@seke3 ~]$ python3

Not root:

```
Python 3.5.2 (default, Feb 20 2017, 22:05:41) 
[GCC 5.1.1 20150618 (Red Hat 5.1.1-4)] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

[seke@seke3 ~]$ pip3.5 -V
pip 8.1.1 from /usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages (python 3.5)
```

Root:

```
[root@seke3 seke]# python3
Python 3.4.2 (default, Jun 20 2016, 14:25:19) 
[GCC 5.3.1 20160406 (Red Hat 5.3.1-6)] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

[root@seke3 seke]# pip3.5
bash: pip3.5: command not find...
```

Answer (score 0):

your instance of pip is installed locally for 3.5 not for root you'll have to install somewhere else to get to it as root like in `/usr/bin`

Comment: but where should I install it and how?